# How to make Paragraph label configurable

Tags: 8, entities, paragraphs

Drupal version 8.4.4

I have a paragraph type defined (For example Links), which only has one field of type link.

And I have Entity reference revisions field in my node edit form.

When I view the node i see the referenced field Label, How to make this label configurable?

Comment: Which label do you mean, of the reference field or of the field in the referenced paragraph? But both are configurable, the first in the content type and the second in the paragraph type.

Comment: The referenced field should be different on different nodes

Comment: ... different on different nodes, then this looks more like content which should be stored in a node field. Hide the label and replace it with a node field in theming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options:

- As commented, either make it a non-paragraph field
- Implement some custom form alter, change the the label there
- Use two different paragraph types with a different label, allow only one of the two on each node type.

Comment: In the case three it will be limited to 2 labels which can be embedded on nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the entity with a custom class and set it as the class to use for that entity type.

Extend the Paragraph entity class and override the `label()` method like this:

```
class ParagraphExt extends Paragraph {
  function label() {
    return "your label";
  }
}
```

Then set it as the class to use in `hook_entity_type_alter` like:

```
function hook_entity_type_alter(array &$entity_types) {
  $entity_types['paragraph']->setClass(ParagraphExt::class);
}
```